# Assign type of variable and class

Tags: c++

Please help me and let me ask a stupid question.
I declared variable x as DeriveType (DeriveType is a class).
I want to assign an int y to x, e.g
int y = x
But when I compile, the compiler shows the error
error: cannot convert 'const DerivType' to 'int'
Please tell me how to solve this problem.
Thank you very much.
Yours sincerely,

This is the Class DerivType

```
class DerivType;

typedef DerivType (*ddf_FctPtr)(const DerivType&);

class DerivType { private: interval f, df, ddf;

public: DerivType ( ); 
DerivType ( const interval&, const interval&, const interval& ); 
DerivType ( const DerivType& );

DerivType& operator= ( const DerivType& );

friend DerivType DerivConst ( const real& );
friend DerivType DerivConst ( const interval& );
friend DerivType DerivVar   ( const real& );
friend DerivType DerivVar   ( const interval& );

friend inline const interval fValue   ( const DerivType& );  
friend inline const interval dfValue  ( const DerivType& );  
friend inline const interval ddfValue ( const DerivType& );  

friend DerivType operator+ ( const DerivType& );
friend DerivType operator- ( const DerivType& );

....
```

And I have a function likes this.

```
DerivType f ( const DerivType& x )
{
        DerivType result;
        DerivType xx;
        double sum;
        xx = x;
        //Convert x from DerivType to double
        void *pVoidx = &xx;                                     [1]
        double *pDoublex = static_cast<double*>(pVoidx);        [2]
        MLPutReal(lp, *pDoublex);

        MLGetReal(lp, &sum);

        //Convert from double to DerivType for the return value of function
        printf( "x = %f, result = %f\n", *pDoublex, sum);
        void *pSum=&sum;                                            [3]
        DerivType *pDerivTypeSum = static_cast<DerivType*>(pSum);   [4]
    return *pDerivTypeSum;
}
```

This function works properly. But my teacher said that it is not the good code, because even the code works in this case, it is still implementation-dependent and architecture-dependent. (He gives me the link: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=195[^])

Can you help me to improve this code, namely [1], [2], [3], [4].

My idea is how to convert from DerivType to double/int and conversely.

Thank for your reading and help.

I am very appriciate about your hints.

Your sincerely

Thank you very much
Yours sincerely,

Comment: What should converting from a `DeriveType` to an `int` mean? You should probably write a conversion operator.

Answer (score 0):

If it makes sense to convert your type to `int`, then you can provide a conversion operator:

```
class DeriveType {
    //...
    operator int() {return <some integer value>;}
    //...
};
```

If it doesn't make sense, then don't write code that tries to do so.

Comment: Thank for your response. You are very nice.

Comment: Dear Pro, how can I use your hits, I can not use: int y = (int) x; It does not work

Comment: @nothingx0x: If the conversion makes sense, then you'll have to add the conversion operator, as I said. If it doesn't make sense, then don't try to do it, as I said.